# Rails related models exits with "NameError uninitialized constant"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I have two models User and Leave

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :leaves
  ...
end

class Leave < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

  #attr_accessible :user_id
  #default_scope -> { order('created_at DESC') }
  validates :user_id, presence: true
 end
```

which are basic models User has many leaves and leaves belongs to user. But when I do

```
@leaves = @user.leaves
```

in users_controller I get this strange error "uninitialized constant User::Leafe" but I cannot find where I have misspelled "leave". Checked all migrations and shema.rb. Prior this code I am calling @leaves2 = Leave.all and that is passing OK but when I do "@user.leaves" it breaks with "500 Internal Server Error" on the console with NameError. Is it possible to do error catching or something similiar to see from where exactly this error is coming.

Also in rails console cant't get @leaves=@user.leaves, it exits with "NameError: uninitialized constant User::Leafe"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Active record sees Singular form of leaves as leaf. You can override it using inflections

config/initializers/inflections.rb

```
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections do |inflect|
  inflect.irregular 'leave', 'leaves'
end
```

Answer (score 0):

One minor note to amend Santhosh's answer. Must include the language modifier (:en)...

```
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections(:en) do |inflect|
  inflect.irregular 'leave', 'leaves'
end
```